# How to plug security into web service with custom SOAP header (java)?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot

Broadly, I'm looking for a way to secure web service implemented in Java (using Spring Boot). I secured it with HTTP basic first.

Currently it is secured using XWSS. The problem is, that soap header for xwss is

```xml
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsse:mustUnderstand="1">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

while I need

```xml
<SecuritySOAPHeader>
    <UserName>user</UserName>
    <Password>password</Password>
</SecuritySOAPHeader>
```

It is "wsdl first" WS, how can I plug security in, when header is defined in WSDL?

**edit:**

If it helps, this is what is defined in WSDL

```xml
<wsdl:binding name="CreditLimitServiceSoap" type="tns:CreditLimitServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://cargowise.com/Accounting/GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails" style="document" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetailsSecuritySOAPHeader" part="SecuritySOAPHeader" use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

It seems, that I'd be able to access the header when I change my current

```
@Endpoint
public class CustomerBalancesEndpoint {
...
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails", )
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetailsResponse getCustomerBalance(@RequestPayload GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails request) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

to

```
@Endpoint
public class CustomerBalancesEndpoint {
...
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails", )
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetailsResponse getCustomerBalance(@RequestHeader SecuritySOAPHeader securityHeader, @RequestPayload GetCreditLimitAndBalanceDetails request) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

As it seems, maven-jaxb2-plugin had no issue with that WSDL.

**edit 2:**

Currently I'm more inclined to modify the message from client (the one with `SecuritySOAPHeader`) and modify it to standard (XWSS) header to have SOAP-ENV:Fault generated if wrong password is passed.

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard header, not even for XWSS, so you have to write your own handlers for this.

Comment: Your code indicates a very specific problem, but your prose sounds very generic. I almost close-voted. I tried to fix this with my edit. Please review my changes for accuracy.

Comment: @Andreas The first one is (AFAIK) XWSS, second example is custom or .NET maybe, I'm not sure...

Comment: @jpaugh Thanks! I thought, that SOAP is a standard and there is just one authentication...

Comment: I was referring to you "need", i.e. the second. I don't think it's .NET either, because a web search for `SecuritySOAPHeader` turns up nothing.